# Regex to replace substring in given xml node only

Tags: c#, xml, regex, xliff

I am trying in vain to write a regex that would only return a match if a given substring "/oem/en" (followed by a forward slash or a double quote" is found in the <target> XML node of a single line XLIFF code. So far here what I got but it is still matching even occurences in <source> nodes:

```
/oem/en(?=/|\")(?=.*?</target>)
```

XLIFF code sample with <source> and <target> nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2"><file product-version="1.4" original="" source-language="default" target-language="default" datatype="plaintext" category="page_content"><header></header><body><trans-unit id="page_description" datatype="x-System.String" maxwidth="0" minwidth="0"><source><![CDATA[bla bla]]></source><target><![CDATA[translated bla bla]]></target></trans-unit><trans-unit id="f55c4d88-1f2e-4ad9-aaa8-819af4ee7ee8" datatype="x-System.String" resname="PublishingPageContent" maxwidth="0" minwidth="0"><source><![CDATA[<a href="/oem/en/link1">bla bla</a>]]></source><target><![CDATA[<a href="/oem/en/link1/>translated bla bla</a>]]></target></trans-unit><trans-unit id="f55c4d88-1f2e-4ad9-aaa8-819af4ee7ee8" datatype="x-System.String" resname="PublishingPageContent" maxwidth="0" minwidth="0"><source><![CDATA[<a href="/oem/en/link2">bla bla</a>]]></source><target><![CDATA[<a href="/oem/en/link2/>translated bla bla</a>]]></target></trans-unit></body></file></xliff>
```

My approach was to try to craft an expression that would look ahead until it matches either an </source> or </target> and if it finds the former first, it means we are in the <source> node and thus it is not a match.

Your help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Nicholas, What language are you using?  Are you capable of replacing a specific capture group?  Is the CData section always expected for *target*'s with */oem/en* values?

Comment: The language is C# and yes I could use capture groups. It seems CDATA section is always expected in the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Description

This expression will find only the `/oem/en` string if it is inside the target tag

regex: `(<target>(?:(?!<\/target>).)*?)(\/oem\/en(?=\/|\"))`

replace with: `$1~~~~New Value~~~~~`

[image]

## C# code example

**Input Text**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2"><file product-version="1.4" original="" source-language="default" target-language="default" datatype="plaintext" category="page_content"><header></header><body><trans-unit id="page_description" datatype="x-System.String" maxwidth="0" minwidth="0"><source><![CDATA[bla bla]]></source><target><![CDATA[translated bla bla]]></target></trans-unit><trans-unit id="f55c4d88-1f2e-4ad9-aaa8-819af4ee7ee8" datatype="x-System.String" resname="PublishingPageContent" maxwidth="0" minwidth="0"><source><![CDATA[<a href="/oem/en/link1">bla bla</a>]]></source><target><![CDATA[<a href="/oem/en/link1/>translated bla bla</a>]]></target></trans-unit><trans-unit id="f55c4d88-1f2e-4ad9-aaa8-819af4ee7ee8" datatype="x-System.String" resname="PublishingPageContent" maxwidth="0" minwidth="0"><source><![CDATA[<a href="/oem/en/link2">bla bla</a>]]></source><target><![CDATA[<a href="/oem/en/link2/>translated bla bla</a>]]></target></trans-unit></body></file></xliff>`

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace myapp
{
  class Class1
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
          String matchpattern = @"(<target>(?:(?!<\/target>).)*?)(\/oem\/en(?=\/|\""))";
          String replacementpattern = @"$1~~~~~new value~~~~~";
          Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(sourcestring,matchpattern,replacementpattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
        }
    }
}
```

**Yields**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2"><file product-version="1.4" original="" source-language="default" target-language="default" datatype="plaintext" category="page_content"><header></header><body><trans-unit id="page_description" datatype="x-System.String" maxwidth="0" minwidth="0"><source><![CDATA[bla bla]]></source><target><![CDATA[translated bla bla]]></target></trans-unit><trans-unit id="f55c4d88-1f2e-4ad9-aaa8-819af4ee7ee8" datatype="x-System.String" resname="PublishingPageContent" maxwidth="0" minwidth="0"><source><![CDATA[<a href="/oem/en/link1">bla bla</a>]]></source><target><![CDATA[<a href="~~~~~new value~~~~~/link1/>translated bla bla</a>]]></target></trans-unit><trans-unit id="f55c4d88-1f2e-4ad9-aaa8-819af4ee7ee8" datatype="x-System.String" resname="PublishingPageContent" maxwidth="0" minwidth="0"><source><![CDATA[<a href="/oem/en/link2">bla bla</a>]]></source><target><![CDATA[<a href="~~~~~new value~~~~~/link2/>translated bla bla</a>]]></target></trans-unit></body></file></xliff>`

Comment: Denomales, How did you produce that diagram?  Also, this will not match the very improbable instance of `<target><![CDATA[<target>x</target><a href="/oem/en/...`

Comment: Brilliant, I was wrecking my head to try and find out a away to match all characters but a substring (I knew how to do it on per character basis such as [^<]* but the part is brilliant! 

(?!<\/target>).)*?

Comment: @Daniel Gimenez, I'm using debuggex.com. Although it doesn't support lookbehinds, named capture groups, or atomic groups it's still handy for understanding the expression flow. There is also regexper.com. They do a pretty good job too, but it's not real time as you're typing.

Comment: @Denomales, all href links instances to replace are inside <target> nodes so your improbably instance won't occur :)

Comment: Hey Daniel, I'll have to give that a try. On the surface it looks pretty cool with the match expander. Did you write/create this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this would be reliable without requiring the CDATA section.

Below is the regex.  It finds the target tag followed by the CDATA.  It then matches any character not followed by the CDATA close ]].  */oem/en* is matched as long as the ]] isn't encountered.  I believe C# supports negated look aheads and non capturing groups.  Obviously negated look aheads are essential.

```
<target><!\[CDATA\[(?:.(?!\]\]))*(/oem/en)
```

If you need to accommodate target having parameters you can do something like `<target[^>]*>`.  If there is going to be whitespace between target and CDATA, then `\w*

I have a regex editor that's very alpha, but you can test it on: http://rey.gimenez.biz/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Daniel, muchas gracias! That would work too provided input is always in CDATA which looks like it is in files I have but I will go with Denomales solution as it is more generic (aka no requirement for CDATA but only anything within <target>)

P.S. i like your web regex editor. I always use desktop tool RegexBuddy which has been a life savior all throughout the years.